# Python Append Timezone info to the datetime index of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

My data frame has datetime index in EST. But this information is not appended to the datetime index. How do i append it?

My code:

```
df.index = 
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01 07:49:28', '2019-10-01 07:50:21',
               '2020-07-25 18:48:44', '2020-07-25 18:49:43',
               '2020-07-25 18:50:43', '2020-07-25 18:51:44'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Unnamed: 0', length=6, freq=None)
df.index = df.index.replace(tzinfo='EST')
```

Present output:

```
    df.index.replace(tzinfo='EST')

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Expected output:

```
df.index = 
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01 07:49:28-05:00', '2019-10-01 07:50:21-05:00',
               '2020-07-25 18:48:44-05:00', '2020-07-25 18:49:43-05:00',
               '2020-07-25 18:50:43-05:00', '2020-07-25 18:51:44-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Unnamed: 0', length=6, freq=None)
```

Comment: EST is not a time zone... please see my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64147223/10197418)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.tz_localize` to add time zone

```
itx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01 07:49:28', '2019-10-01 07:50:21',
                        '2020-07-25 18:48:44', '2020-07-25 18:49:43',
                        '2020-07-25 18:50:43', '2020-07-25 18:51:44'],
                        dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Unnamed: 0')

itx = itx.tz_localize(tz='EST')

Out[285]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-01 07:49:28-05:00', '2019-10-01 07:50:21-05:00',
               '2020-07-25 18:48:44-05:00', '2020-07-25 18:49:43-05:00',
               '2020-07-25 18:50:43-05:00', '2020-07-25 18:51:44-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, EST]', name='Unnamed: 0', freq=None)
```

Comment: `EST` is not a time zone but an offset from UTC of certain time zone(s) at a certain time of the year. Assuming the data originates from a certain time zone (here: US/Eastern), localizing to EST is wrong; US/Central has DST, so the UTC offset changes from EST to EDT.