# Python Convert Daylight Saving time to Standard Zone time

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, timezone, dst

I have data coming from field (Florida), which saves it in local time. Florida has day light saving time. So, I want to convert this to EST zone. How do I do it?
My code:

```
local_df.index = DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-01 06:58:45', '2019-10-01 06:59:00',
               '2019-10-01 06:59:15', 
               '2020-07-18 09:16:30', '2020-07-18 09:16:45'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='', freq=None)
est_df.index = local_df.index.tz_localize(tz='EST')
est_df.index = DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-01 06:58:45-05:00', '2019-10-01 06:59:00-05:00',
               '2019-10-01 06:59:15-05:00','2020-07-18 09:16:30-05:00', '2020-07-18 09:16:45-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='', freq=None)
```

My above code is actually not converting local time to the eastern standard time, it appends only the time difference with UCT. This is not correct.

Comment: There's no "standard" timezone and EST is an ambiguous acronym, not a timezone name. There are 3 ISTs and 3 BSTs for example. The de-facto (and only) standard are [the IANA timezone database names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), using names like `America/Dawson`

Comment: by the way, here's a nice contribution by Matt Johnson-Pint, shedding some light on the `EST` issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163955/10197418

Answer (score 1):

Note that `EST` is not a time zone but an offset from UTC of certain time zone(s) at a certain time of the year. I suggest to use [IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) instead for an unambiguous geographical attribution. Side note: Florida has two time zones; US/Eastern and US/Central.

Furthermore, to *convert* UTC time to a time zone's time, you'll have to localize to UTC first. Your code could look something like

```
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-01 06:58:45', '2019-10-01 06:59:00', '2019-10-01 06:59:15', 
                        '2020-07-18 09:16:30', '2020-07-18 09:16:45'])

dti_UTC = dti.tz_localize('UTC')
dti_USEastern = dti_UTC.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# dti_USEastern
# DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-01 02:58:45-04:00', '2019-10-01 02:59:00-04:00',
#                '2019-10-01 02:59:15-04:00', '2020-07-18 05:16:30-04:00',
#                '2020-07-18 05:16:45-04:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]', freq=None)
```

If, however, the input resembles *local time*, say US/Eastern, you can directly localize to that time zone:

```
dti_USEastern = dti.tz_localize('US/Eastern')

# dti_USEastern
# DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-01 06:58:45-04:00', '2019-10-01 06:59:00-04:00',
#                '2019-10-01 06:59:15-04:00', '2020-07-18 09:16:30-04:00',
#                '2020-07-18 09:16:45-04:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]', freq=None)
```

Comment: A good example of the ambiguity are IST and BST - [there are 3 of each](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). No-one controls the acronyms so nothing prevents a country, eg Estonia, from starting to use `EST` for its own timezone(s) at any time instead of EEST.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: jep, nice example! I wonder why this even works in `pandas` (`pytz` etc.). I mean, setting a UTC offset is fine but allowing to use some abbreviation for that which people associate with a time zone which in fact has a varying UTC offset? But I guess I'm not the first to notice that; there likely is *some* reason... At least it seems to fail for the ambiguous candidates like IST.

Comment: Hand-coded defaults added early on probably. You should see the equivalent tz and Unicode mess in R, where people just run packages *locally* on their Macs and Linux machines using local codepages and timezones (because what else is there?). Then they started using files from other countries, with different encodings, number and time formats and discovered many packages and functions *didn't* accept an encoding or timezone parameter

Comment: Ok. Can you help me to understand something here. My local time is `'2019-06-01 06:58:45'`. When converted to EST, I am expecting something like one hour difference. But, here I see `'2019-06-01 02:58:45-04:00'`. My question is, what does `'2019-06-01 02:58:45-04:00'` actually mean? I mean what is the actual time it is saying?

Comment: @Mainland: made an edit, showing what I think is what you need. Two more remarks: 1) `'2019-06-01 06:58:45'` doesn't hold any info related to time zone so you can't convert it, you need to localize it, and 2) you don't "convert" to EST because that means setting a UTC offset, not more. A string like `'2019-06-01 02:58:45-04:00'` would mean `2:58 am local` with -4 hours offset to UTC, so UTC would be `6:58 am`. This could be in *any* time zone at UTC-4 at that time; the `-04:00` doesn't give you unambiguous geographical info.