# Python time zones: Why is EST off by one hour? (pytz / dateutil)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, python-dateutil

I'm trying to print the current time in EST, but my results are off by one hour (when compared to Google's "est local time" and "nyc local time"). I've tried using both `pytz` and `dateutil`:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz
import pytz

# Correct
print(datetime.datetime.now())

# Correct
print(datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.UTC))

# Off by one hour
print(str(datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.gettz("EST"))))

# Off by one hour
print(str(pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow()).astimezone(pytz.timezone("EST"))))
```

I've tried to research the correct way to do this, and the above is what I've found, yet the result is off (e.g. it shows 10 am EST when Google says it's 11 am). My local time is configured correctly. Am I missing something?

I'm using:

- Python 3.8.5
- python-dateutil 2.8.1
- pytz 2020.1

Comment: The current timezone  in NYC is EDT, not EST.

Comment: Neither EDT nor EST is a standard timezone name. It's just an abbreviation that could be reused for *many* different timezones. There are 3 ISTs and 3 BSTs for example. The de-facto standard are the IANA timezone names. Use `America/New_York` instead of the date-specific EDT and EST

Comment: Thanks! @PanagiotisKanavos, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Barmar, if I replace EST with EDT in the sample code, dateutil is several hours off, and pytz does not recognize EDT.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, if EST is ambiguous, why are dateutil and pytz silently swallowing it instead of emitting an error?

Comment: If it wasn't ambiguous, you wouldn't be asking this question. You though this was a timezone name and found out it's more like an offset used in a specific timezone part of the year. Try using `IST` or `BST`. What happens? The fact that tools recognize some acronyms doesn't mean they aren't ambiguous. *Nobody* controls those abbreviations, so nothing prevents eg Estonia from starting to use EST. Just as nothing prevented Israel, Ireland and India from using IST.

Comment: They use whatever is in your system's timezone configuration file. Systems in the US use the American meanings of these timezones, other countries use their own.

Comment: @Barmar there's no reason to do this. *Everyone* uses the IANA timezone names. `America/New_York` is unambiguous

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When dates are displayed to users, it's normal to use the locale-specific abbreviations.

Comment: BTW there are two PSTs in the list of [timezone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). Pacific Standard Time and Phillipine Standard Time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And users don't normally enter timezones using IANA names.

Comment: @Barmar actually, they do. They may display it differently, but underneath they use the IANA names. When you went to book a flight you saw `PDT` or `EST` as the flight time but the actual timezone posted by the airline and used by the travel agency was the IANA timezone, plus an explicit offset. I work for an OTA, so I know this is the case. Linux works the same way too. So do web sites like WordPress

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that's how it works under the covers, but user interfaces use abbreviations because that's what humans are familiar with. IANA names are just for programmers.

Comment: @Barmar in any case *this* question isn't about what to display to the user. It's why `EST` returned the wrong time. Because it's the wrong name to use, one has to know in advance whether daylight saving time is in effect. Which kind of defeats the purpose.  By using `America/New_York` though,  there's no problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I said above, I was explaining why the tools swallow them, I wasn't justifying using them in code.

Comment: the point here I think is the confusion of a time zone, which has a geographical meaning and abbreviations that are *associated* with time zones. These, like `EST` or `EDT`, are not time zones, they are offsets from UTC - which a certain time zone can have during a certain time. That is a fundamental difference. EST would basically just set a UTC offset of -5 hours; which would be wrong for the east cost during summer! Side note @PanagiotisKanavos can't believe there's another one of these questions on one day :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Unfortunately `EST` is actually an IANA zone name, and the cause of this confusion.  See my answer.

Comment: The Time Lord has come ; Also (facepalm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time is off by an hour because daylight saving time is in effect at this time, and that is not represented when you specified `EST`.

As mentioned in the question's comments - you should use a specific locality-based time zone name, such as `America/New_York` instead of `EST`.

The reason `EST` works in both pytz and dateutil is that it *is* defined as an IANA time zone name:

From: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2020a/northamerica#L188-L206

> We generate the files specified below to guard against old files with
> obsolete information being left in the time zone binary directory.
> We limit the list to names that have appeared in previous versions of
> this time zone package...
>
> ```
> # Zone  NAME     STDOFF  RULES  FORMAT  [UNTIL]
> Zone    EST       -5:00  -      EST
> Zone    MST       -7:00  -      MST
> Zone    HST      -10:00  -      HST
> Zone    EST5EDT   -5:00  US     E%sT
> Zone    CST6CDT   -6:00  US     C%sT
> Zone    MST7MDT   -7:00  US     M%sT
> Zone    PST8PDT   -8:00  US     P%sT
> ```

As you can see, `EST`, `MST`, and `HST` are defined with fixed offsets.  They do not observe any DST rules.  There are no similar entries for `PST` or `CST`, nor for daylight variants like `EDT`.

The zones with names like `EST5EDT` are backwards compatible with older POSIX-style time zones, but only these 4 are defined.

Generally speaking, you should not use any of these zones.  They are there for the guard only.