# American time zones like CT, give error: ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key CT'

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo, tzdata

Python 3.9 introduced the `zoneinfo` module:

> The `zoneinfo` module provides a concrete time zone implementation to support the IANA time zone database as originally specified in PEP 615. By default, `zoneinfo` uses the system’s time zone data if available; if no system time zone data is available, the library will fall back to using the first-party `tzdata` package available on PyPI.

On my Ubuntu machine, it supports lots of time zones:

```
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> ZoneInfo("America/New_York")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/New_York')
>>> ZoneInfo("MST") # Mountain Standard Time
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='MST')
>>> ZoneInfo("CET") # Central European Time
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='CET')
```

However, it doesn't seem to support some time zones abbreviations used in North America like Central Time (CT), Central Standard Time (CST) or Pacific Standard Time (PST).

```
>>> ZoneInfo("CT")
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key CT'
>>> ZoneInfo("CST")
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key CST'
>>> ZoneInfo("PST")
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key PST'
```

How can I get the right `ZoneInfo` objects for time zones like CT, CST or PST? Is the time zone database lacking? Does it depend on the operating system that I'm running?

Comment: Many of the [tz name abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) are ambiguous. Might be ok for display to a user, but you do not want to have that in your code. Time zone rules and their political background are enough to deal with, no?

Comment: see also [Python: datetime tzinfo time zone names documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861179/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issues with the abbreviations CT (Central Time), CST (Central Standard Time), PT (Pacific Time), and PST (Pacific Standard Time). Here are the main two:

- They do not identify a unique time zone. For example, CST could stand for Central Standard Time, but it could also stand for Cuban Standard Time or China Standard Time. The IANA database of time zones lists CST for all these areas.
- CST and PST are not appropriate during the summer, as most parts of the USA switch to daylight savings time during the period of the year that includes the summer. During the summer, the terms CDT (Central Daylight Time) and PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) should be used instead.

### Central:

Instead of CT (CST during the winter or CDT during the summer), use `US/Central` or `Canada/Central` IANA identifier instead:

```py
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> ZoneInfo("US/Central")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Central')
```

### Pacific:

Instead of PT (PST during the winter or PDT during the summer), use `US/Pacific` or `Canada/Pacific` instead:

```py
>>> ZoneInfo("US/Pacific")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Pacific')
```

### Mountain:

For MT (MST during the winter and MDT during the summer), use `US/Mountain` for the areas that follow daylight savings time during the summer, and use `America/Phoenix` for the parts of Arizona that use MST all year round.

```py
>>> ZoneInfo("US/Mountain")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Mountain')
>>> ZoneInfo("America/Phoenix")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Phoenix')
```

Note that Python does accept `MST` as a key. This identifier does not follow daylight savings time though, which you may not expect.

### Eastern:

For ET (EST during the winter or EDT during the summer), use `US/Eastern` or `Canada/Eastern`:

```py
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> ZoneInfo("US/Eastern")
zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern')
```

Note that Python does accept `EST` as a key. This identifier does not follow daylight savings time though, which you may not expect.

[image: US Map]

(Notice that parts of Arizona on the map represented by Phoenix don't observe Daylight Time)

Comment: Even names like 'US/Central' are kind of unspecific and you find them in the IANA database mainly for backwards compatibility. Check out Paul Eggert's [tz repo](https://github.com/eggert/tz) if you want to dig deep. Especially all the comments ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner Interesting. Python's zoneinfo seems to think that `US/Central` is not overly ambiguous since it does return a `ZoneInfo` object for that key. I'm curious to know if there is a better choice than `US/Central` and `Canada/Central` when trying to interpret the CST abbreviation in North America.

Comment: that's probably pretty application-specific, how precise you have to be or can be. If you start with "CST", you're in for a guessing game anyway :) China Standard Time vs. US/Central or America/Chicago doesn't seem like a big difference for instance.

Comment: The IANA identifiers `MST` and `EST` are *fixed offset* zones without DST, which is not actually the norm in the areas you're indicating.  They should not be recommended.  See notes in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64163955/634824

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks. I've edited my answer to no longer recommend `MST` and `EST`

Answer (score 2):

Zoneinfo, pytz, and others use IANA time zones.  You can find a complete list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

In general, the abbreviations you specified are obsolete zones that should not be used.  They only exist for backwards compatibility purposes.

In particular:

- `EST`, `MST`, and `HST` are [defined here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/85dbb1ae5bced2e1c9c2e30a6e068596499e6d48/northamerica#L200-L202).  They are fixed time zones with offsets of -5, -7, and -10 respectively.  They do not have any DST rules.
- `WET`, `CET`, `MET`, and `EET` are [defined here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/85dbb1ae5bced2e1c9c2e30a6e068596499e6d48/europe#L736-L739).  They have offsets 0, +1, +1, and +2 respectively, and follow European DST rules, without regard to any specific country.

There are a few others, but none of them should be used.

You asked about `CT`, `CST`, and `PST` - these are not defined in the IANA data, and that's a good thing.  Abbreviations are not identifiers.

As far as the recommended identifiers, that depends very much on the country and how far back you need to support.  The *current* list of all time zones in active use within the USA (considering only states, not territories) is:

- `America/New_York` - Eastern time zone
- `America/Chicago` - Central time zone
- `America/Denver` - Mountain time zone
- `America/Phoenix` - Mountain time zone without DST, used in most of Arizona
- `America/Los_Angeles` - Pacific time zone
- `America/Anchorage` - Alaska time zone
- `America/Adak` - Aleutian time zone (far west isles of Alaska)
- `Pacific/Honolulu` - Hawaiian time zone

Note that I've chosen to use locality-based time zones, as this is the current best practice.

You also asked:

> Does it depend on the operating system that I'm running?

Python uses IANA identifiers on all major operating systems.  The choice of OS does not change the type of time zone ID you use with Python.

Comment: "*IANA identifiers are used on all major operating systems*" - Windows still uses its own system, no? I remember it being kind of a hack to get IANA tz names out of Windows system configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is eye opening to someone like me. What about the identifiers that start with `US` like `US/Aleutian`, `US/Pacific`, `US/Arizona`, `US/Hawaii`, `US/East-Indiana`, `US/Indiana-Starke`, `US/Michigan`, `US/Eastern`, `US/Central`, `US/Samoa`, `US/Alaska`, `US/Mountain` ? Would you recommend using them?

Comment: @FObersteiner I agree, there are African countries missing from Windows' database, for instance. I doubt that Windows uses the IANA database.

Comment: The question was about *Python*.  Python uses IANA identifiers on all OS's, *including Windows*.

Comment: But yes, Windows itself does support IANA identifiers, just not on all APIs.  WinRT/UWP APIs use them, but not Win32.  .NET 6+ also supports them when ICU is installed. Java on Windows uses them.  Just about everything on Windows uses them *except* Win32 APIs, or older .NET Framework, or cmd/pwsh commands that use those older APIs.

Comment: @Flimm - Regarding `US/` timezones, they are also old-style aliases.  See the notes in the chart on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones which shows the recommended canonical zone.

Comment: ... and of that list, you no long need to show `US/East-Indiana, US/Indiana-Starke, US/Michigan` (for *current* times).  And if you were going to include `US/Samoa` (which is for *American Samoa*, not the Independent State of Samoa), then you'd probably also want the other US territories in your list as well.  That would be, `Pacific/Pago_Pago` (AS), `Pacific/Guam` (GU), and `America/Puerto_Rico` (PR).  (Note that MP and GU are in the same time zone, as are PR and VI.)

Answer (score 1):

Per: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html

> The zoneinfo module does not directly provide time zone data, and
> instead pulls time zone information from the system time zone database
> or the first-party PyPI package tzdata

There are a number of utility methods you likely can call to help debug.  Read that pages though as many of these methods come with caveats and/or warnings.

I might start with:

`zoneinfo.available_timezones()`

but that comes with the following:

> Get a set containing all the valid keys for IANA time zones available
> anywhere on the time zone path. This is recalculated on every call to
> the function.
>
> This function only includes canonical zone names and does not include
> “special” zones such as those under the posix/ and right/ directories,
> or the posixrules zone.
>
> Caution This function may open a large number of files, as the best
> way to determine if a file on the time zone path is a valid time zone
> is to read the “magic string” at the beginning.
>
> Note These values are not designed to be exposed to end-users; for
> user facing elements, applications should use something like CLDR (the
> Unicode Common Locale Data Repository) to get more user-friendly
> strings. See also the cautionary note on ZoneInfo.key.